# Unity - How to store a Dictionary in a serializedObject property

Tags: unity, c#

I'm writing a custom editor for my `GridModel` object. The object has 2 fields; `Vector2Int dimensions` and a `Dictionary<Vector2Int, bool> grid` variable. Since the script will mostly be editted in the prefab editor, I save the fields with the `serializedObject` property. This works fine for the `dimensions` variable, but the `serializedObject.FindProperty("grid")` method returns `null`. My guess is this is because the `Dictionary` object is not serializable.

My question therefor is, how can I save the `Dictionary` type in the `serializedObject` property to make sure the `grid` field is the same in the prefab editor as in any other editor?

These are my scripts:

```
public class GridModel : MonoBehaviour, IGridModel
{
    public Dictionary<Vector2Int, bool> grid;
    public Vector2Int dimensions;
}


CustomEditor(typeof(GridModel))]
public class GridModelEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        Vector2Int dimensions = EditorGUILayout.Vector2IntField("Size", serializedObject.FindProperty("dimensions").vector2IntValue);
        serializedObject.FindProperty("dimensions").vector2IntValue = dimensions;
        SerializedProperty serializedField = serializedObject.FindProperty("grid"); // Returns null
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the [Custom Serialization guide from the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization-Custom.html) to serialize your dictionary into a flat array of {Vector2Int, bool} pairs, and deserialize it back to a dictionary on load/change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are right, Unity cannot serialize standard dictionaries. I've used [this library](https://github.com/azixMcAze/Unity-SerializableDictionary) to serialize Dictionaries in my projects before. The README has a lot of great info features, limitations and usage. In your case, it would be:

```
public class GridModel : MonoBehaviour, IGridModel
{
    // This class can be defined elsewhere if desired
    [Serializable]
    public class Vec2iBoolDictionary : SerializableDictionary<Vector2Int, bool>;
    
    public Vec2iBoolDictionary grid; // This dictionary should now be serializable
    public Vector2Int dimensions;
}
```

Since `Vec2iBoolDictionary` inherits from `SerializableDictionary` which in turn inherits from `Dictionary` I don't believe you will have to change any other parts of your code that use the Dictionary. I'm not sure if there are any further steps when writing a custom editor, typically I'll just use the default editor.